# Women going out of the house for leisure

Tags: quran, tafseer, women

Does the verse 'and stay in your houses' refer to all muslim women because the command to not be soft in speech and not do tabarujj in that verse refers to all muslim women? Please refer to the opinion of classical/prominent scholars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quran verse 33:33 was a direct commandment to the Prophet's wives only. So why do people say it is supposed to be for ALL Muslim women?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/quran-verse-3333-was-a-direct-commandment-to-the-prophets-wives-only-so-why-d)

Comment: I would like the different scholarly opinions on this issue. The question you referenced, only states one opinion.

Comment: I want this so I can research the different opinions. I don't think that this is an issue on which there is scholarly consensus.

Answer (score 1):

Aslamu Walaykum

The act of tabarujj is haram, it's purpose is to look more nicer, and attract men to look which is prohibited.

Abdullah bin Mas’oud (رضي الله عنه) reported that the Prophet (صَلَّى اللّٰهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم) “Used to dislike ten kinds of behavior and he (Abdullah) mentioned amongst them: “Tabarruj by means of displaying beautification in an improper place.”(23). Imam As- Suyouti, may Allah’s mercy be upon him, said: “Tabarruj by displaying beautification is showing off to strangers and this is disliked. This is the explanation of “an improper place.” It is not so if the beautification is done for the husband.

(21) Saheeh Al-Bukhari (English-Arabic, Dar Al-Arabia, Publ. Beirut,Lebanon), V.9, hadeeth # 384, p.284
(22) Related by Imam Ahmed in his Mussnad 4/101-Arabic.
(23) Related by An-Nissa’ee in his ” Sunan “Arabic 8/141.

Umay’mah, the daughter of Ruqay’ah came to the Messenger of Allah (صَلَّى اللّٰهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم) to acknowledge the message of Islam and that he (صَلَّى اللّٰهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم) is the Messenger of Allah. The Prophet (صَلَّى اللّٰهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم) told her:

“I give my acknowledgment that you must not set partners to worship besides Allah and that you don’t steal or commit fornication and adultery, that you don’t kill your child, that you don’t commit any falsehood before your hands and between your legs, that you don’t wail, and that you don’t make Tabarruj like that of Jaahiliyyah“ (24).

It is clear that the Prophet (صَلَّى اللّٰهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّم) associated Tabarruj with grave destructive sins.

“Of the people of Hell there are two types whom I have never seen, the one possessing whips like the tail of an ox and they flog people with them. The second one, women who would be naked in spite of their being dressed, who are seduced (to wrong paths) and seduce others with their hair high like humps. These women would not get into Al-Jannah and they would not perceive its odor, although its fragrance can be perceived from such and such distance.” (26)

Therefore, tabarujj is haram.