# Who is Abdullah ibn Dinar Al-Bahrani?

Tags: islamic-scholar, isnad

Ibn Hanbal often quotes chains originating from Abdullah ibn Dinar Al-Bahrani.
I have not been able to obtain any information about him. According to the length of the chains, he must have lived in the 2nd generation after Muhammad ﷺ, probably at the same time as his well-known homologue Malik ibn Dinar al-Basri (whom Ibn Hanbal also quotes, with distinguishable chains, so that it can be excluded that they are identical). He may be counted among the tabiun.

Does anyone know details of his life, knowledge and relationships?

Comment: Some of the narrators have little biography about them, however it does not affect the grade of hadith if a unknown narrator narrated as long as it a sahaba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are two well-known ibn Dinar's and a rather unknown one who are known for their hadith transmission.

I think it makes sense to shortly present all three of them so that readers may find a way to distinguish them later:

#### 'Abdullah ibn Dinar al-Bahrani [عبد الله بن دينار البهراني](https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A&oldid=64203612)

This seems to be the person you are asking for in your inquiry, that's why I'll try to provide as much as possible of information about him unlike the other two scholars with the same surename.
His name as presented by scholars like al-Mizzi in Tahdeeb al-Kamal تهذيب الكمال في أسماء الرجال is:
 <sup>Here and in the following I'll translate from Arabic, as these translations are mainly of my own with the support of translation tools like Google Translate. Take them with the necessary care!</sup>

> عبد الله بن دينار البهراني ، ويقال : الأسدي ، أبو محمد الشامي الحمصي ، ويقال : إنه دمشقي . والصحيح أنه حمصي . ([Source](https://shamela.ws/book/3722/7403#p1) and the following pages)
> 'Abdullah ibn Dinar al-Bahrani and it is said: Al-Asadi, Abu Muhammad A-Shami Al-Himsi, and it is said: He is a Damascene. The correct is that he is a Himsi.

His teachers are: Hareez حريز also known as abu Hareez mawla of Mu'awiyah for whom al-Mizzi also wrote a kind of biography in the above-named book. Note that in Tareekh Dimashq ibn 'Asakir claimed that the correct name is Jarir. Other teachers are 'Ataa' ibn abi Rabah عطاء بن أبي رباح , 'Umar ibn 'Abdal'aziz عمر بن عبد العزيز , Kathir ibn 'Alaa' a student of abu Hurairah, ibn Shihab az-Zuhri الزهري , Makhool مكحول, Abu Malik a-Shar'abi أبو عامر الشرعبي and Nafi' the mawla of ibn 'Umar.

You may note that all these teachers are from a-Shaam or were known to have spent a certain part of their lives there, and so is the case of his students among them you may find Isma'el ibn Ayyash إسماعيل بن عياش.Ibn 'Asakir mentioned many statements of scholars of hadith which claim that Isma'el ibn 'Ayyash was his only narrator. However al-Mizzi added others like Ishaaq ibn Tha'labah al-Himyari إسحاق بن ثعلبة الحميري and Sulayman ibn 'Ataa' al-Harani سليمان بن عطاء الحراني unlike Isma'el ibn 'Ayyash these narrators are mainly agreed upon to be weak narrators or narrators of fabrications or strangnesses.

From the above we conclude that he was tabi' at-Tabiyn and on the same level as scholars like Malik ibn Anas, the two Sufyan's, al-Laith ibn Sa'ad etc.. Ibn Majah only compiled one hadith via him via his teacher Hareez:

> حَدَّثَنَا هِشَامُ بْنُ عَمَّارٍ، حَدَّثَنَا إِسْمَاعِيلُ بْنُ عَيَّاشٍ، حَدَّثَنَا **عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ دِينَارٍ**، حَدَّثَنَا **حَرِيزٌ، مَوْلَى مُعَاوِيَةَ** قَالَ خَطَبَ مُعَاوِيَةُ بِحِمْصَ فَذَكَرَ فِي خُطْبَتِهِ أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ نَهَى عَنِ النَّوْحِ ‏.‏
> **Hareez**<sup>(*)</sup>, the freed slave of Mu’awiyah, said:
> “Mu’awiyah delivered a sermon in Hims, and in his sermon, he mentioned that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) forbade wailing.” (see [here](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1580))

(*) *Hareez* is my correction here of the clear error of the translator who claimed it was Jarir, while the Arabic text says otherwise. As-Sindi in his commentary again pointed at the fact that the name Jarir is also used.

Here are some scholarly qualifications on him (in short).
He was qualified as weak by:

- Abu Hathim ar-Razi.
- Yahya ibn Maiyn.
- A-Daraqotni.
- ibn 'Ady who quoted him in his al-Kamil fi a-Do'afaa'.

And trustworthy by:

- Ibn Hebban quoted him in his "A-Theqaat".
- Abu Ali also known as al-Hafidh from Nishapure.

See also on [hadithtransmitters](http://hadithtransmitters.hawramani.com/%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%A8%D9%86-%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%87%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%8A/) (Arabic side with sources, not all of them pointing at the correct person) where you may find a statement of Ahmad ibn Hanbal distinguishing him from 'Abdullah ibn Dinar al-'Adawi or al Madani who directly narrated from ibn 'Umar. Al-Bukhari also mentioned him in his a-Tareekh al-Kabir.

See also: [Is there a scale or classification for scholars and their qualification of hadith narrators?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46562/is-there-a-scale-or-classification-for-scholars-and-their-qualification-of-hadit)

#### 'Abdullah ibn Dinar [عبد الله بن دينار](https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B1&oldid=64522747)

This 'Abdullah ibn Dinar known as al-'Adawi, al-'Umari since he was a mawla of ibn 'Umar () and he is from Medina. He is also referred to as abu 'Abdarrahman. He is a known mohhadith and widely accepted hadith narrator, who heard and met some of the sahabah like 'Abdullah ibn 'Umar, Anas ibn Malik, Sulayman ibn Yasar and abu Salih as-Saman to name some of which are mentioned on Wikipedia. He died depending on the sources of reports either 127 a.H. or 136 a.H..
Among his most prominent students, you may find the imams Malik ibn Anas, Sho'abah, the two Sufyans a-Thawri and ibn 'Uyyanah and many more. He's the only source of a hadith narrated in both sahihs:

> Malik related to me from Abdullah ibn Dinar from Abdullah ibn Umar that the Messenger of Allah, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, forbade selling or giving away the wala'.
> ([al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/514840) and see also [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1506a)(**) and by al-Bukhari via [Sufyan](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6756), via [Sho'bah](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2535))

<sup>(**)</sup> The [second version in Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1506b) counts a whole bunch of narrators of 'Abdullah ibn Dinar among them both Sufyan's a-Thawri (Sufyan ibn Sa'id  سفيان بن سعيد) and ibn 'Uyynah beside Sho'abah alone this list shows a huge amount of ibn Dinar's students.

As stated earlier imam Ahmad pointed at the difference between both 'Abdullah ibn Dinar's which is that **one heard ibn 'Umar** () and reported from him as he certainly met him, while the other reports via intermedia of Nafi' from ibn 'Umar, as he never met a sahahbi().

#### [Malik ibn Dinar](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Malik_Dinar&oldid=1205002467) [مالك بن دينار](https://ar.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B1&oldid=63493176)

Malik ibn Dinar or abu Yahya Malik ibn Dinar al-Basri (Wikipedia claims he died 748 A.D. while a-Dhahabi quoted 127 a.H. or 130 a.H. others quoted other years so he might have died between 123 A.H.- 131 A.H.). He met and narrated from Anas ibn Malik and al-Ahnaf ibn Qays. He is known for being a preacher, moralist and a quran copiest. 'Ali al-Madini said he has narrated around 40 hadith, and a-Daraqotni said: although he is trustworthy none of those who narrated from him are.
He also narrated from known tabi'yn like ibn Sireen and al-Hasasn from Basra. An-Nasa-i also considered him as trustworthy and al-Bukhari mentioned his hadith statements in his introductory words in his sahih (without sanad). Among his students, we may find Sa'id ibn abi 'Arubah  سعيد بن أبي عروبة, 'Abdullah ibn Shadhoob عبد الله بن شوذب, Hammam ibn Yahya ibn Dinar همام بن يحيى, Abaan ibn Yazid al-'Attar أبان بن يزيد العطار, 'Abdussalam ibn Harb عبد السلام بن حرب a teacher of abu Bakr ibn Shaybah.

Here are two ahadith of him one in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:248) and al-Bukhari's [al-Adab al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/urn/2302800)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't aware that there are even two Abdulah ibn Dinar, and I thought that it al-Bahrani was often omitted. Recounting the references, al-Bahrani is a much less important source than I thought.